# How can I change the font on the desktop icons so there is no shadow?

Tags: icons

I cannot read the icon labels with the shadow text it is using on my desktop. I am running windows 10

Comment: A web search on "remove shadow text desktop icon Windows 10" found this among many other answers https://www.top-password.com/blog/remove-shadow-under-icon-text-on-windows-10-desktop/

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on This PC (Computer) and select Properties. In the Window that comes up, choose Advanced System Settings.

In the new window, click on Advanced, then Performance options, and then at (near) the bottom, uncheck "Use Drop Shadow for Icon Labels on Desktop"   .

That should do it for you. It does for me here.

Follow up note:  It may be that, upon making the proper settings, you still see a shadow. This can be corrected.  As per the instructions above, first set to "Adjust for best Appearance", then apply. Now uncheck 3 items:  Shadow under mouse pointer, Shadows under Windows, Use Drop Shadow under icon labels".  Close out and immediately restart the computer. It should be fine upon restart. Why did I add this?  I just created a new user profile on a Windows Insider computer and had to do as I suggest above to remove all trace of shadow. Works.